# Отображение данных в формате "ключ-значение" с возможностью редактирования

Tags: android

Нужно отобразить данные в формате "ключ-значение" с возможностью редактирования. То есть, что-то вроде:

```
Фамилия: Иванов (текст)
Имя: Петр (текст)
Год рождения: 1999 (дата)
Гуляет по ночам: Нет (checkbox)
Сколько нужно денег для счастья: 5 руб (ползунок, макс и мин значения известны)
```

И т.д. Это только для примера. То есть все "ключи" известны, и их мало, скажем, штук 10.

Как легче и лучше всего это сделать? Я нашел 100 и 1 способ и запутался.

обновлен1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есил вам известны 100 способов это сделать, то лучше и легче взять 1-й.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут все просто. Разберем на примере фамилии:

1. В разметке ставишь `TextView` с текстом "Фамилия: " и рядом `EditText`.
2. В коде находишь `EditText` (`findViewById(R.id.Твой_EditText);`), а потом в него вставляешь в него текст: `setText("Иванов");`
3. Отредактирует фамилию, "возьмешь" ее с `EditText` (через `.getText().toString()`) и сделаешь то, что тебе нужно.

Чтобы проделать это же с датой или ползунком — подставляешь соответствующие `View` (как им установить значение без проблем найдешь в гугле).

---

Вот максимально упрощенная разметка, корректируй, как душе угодно :)

Установи правильно `android:id=@+id/` и текст. Текст в `EditText` и остальное нужно вставлять через Java код.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Фамилия"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Имя"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Год рождения"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Гуляет по ночам"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Нужно денег для счастья"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Готово"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: мне бы главное создать правильно layout и там все разметить. как это правильно сделать? то есть, чтобы они все были в форме таблицы или что-то вроде.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, там тоже все просто, сейчас напишу.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, добавил максимально простую разметку.

Comment: тут разве не должно быть родительского контейнера в котором будут лежать все эти LinearLayout и кнопка? или оставить relative layout по-умолчанию, который создается, когда я добавляю новое activity и положить, то завернуть это все в нее?

Comment: обновил вопрос. завернул все в relative layout (LinearLayout оставил внутри, просто relative layout снаружи), выглядит так, что надписи друг на друга понаехали.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, странно... Родительский контейнер не скопировался. Нет, тут нужен `LinearLayout` с `android:orientation="vertical"

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, все исправил.

Comment: работает, спасибо.